# how to make text over the image using css while dynamically displaying the image and the text from backend using custom template in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using custom template in wordpress. This is the code

```
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
        <img class="home-img" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <p><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></p>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

which is displaying category with category images like this [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZByx.jpg).
I want to display the text **on**  the image not below the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the position of the paragraph:

```
p { 
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but i can't get text in the center of the image.

Comment: thanks again but i want to make it center aligned from top and bottom as well.

Comment: Play with the top margin. Giving it a lower value will move the text up.